# How do you change text in a textbox AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, textfield

I have a TextField called "textbox". I have this code:

```
textbox.text = 'hello';
```

the code is right but its not changing the text when played. The previous text clears but the new text (**hello**) doesn't appear.
I'm guessing its something to do with the properties but i just don't know what.

Comment: One common caveat people run into when dragging a text field on the stage is that it isn't large enough to show all your text. To see if this is your issue, try doing:  `textbox.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;`.

Answer (score 3):

1) The font you are using have not been embedded for those characters you are writing
 - Solution for that is to click on the textfield in Flash IDE, select "embed font" and select the characters you want to embed (Basic Latin should do the trick for you)

2) The textfield is not visible : access it by textbox.visible = true

3) The textfield is too small to show the text, make sure to make it big enough to show the text

That is the basic stuff, let me know if that didn't solve it

Answer (score 0):

since its a little escription, i can think of many things.
- is textbox added to stage?
- is textbox visible?
- do you call the function?

try inserting a breakpoint to the line, launch in debug mode, and see what happens.

The code itself should work. just be sure it gets called. a great tool for that is trace();
for example:

```
trace("calling textbox:", textbox.text); //the output panel should say the current text in textbox
textbox.text = 'hello'; //set text
trace("calling textbox:", textbox.text); //see it the text is being set.
```

If you see nothing in the output panel, function does not get called.
If you see it changing, it means the textbox is not visible.
If it works, it works. :)

Comment: Okay Sorry for little detail, The textbox changes but it is not visible, How do i change that? Thank you for the reply

Comment: well it depends.. try trace(textbox.x, textbox.y) and if it is in the visible area (between 0 and swf's width and height) you position it (textbox.x=0, textbox.y=0). If its not even added to stage (stage.contains(textbox)==false) you should add it with addchild..

Comment: I see you're new to flash, check this out for your problem: http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3text/